# CSS selector with many conditions (nth-child, not and visibility)

Tags: css, visible, css-selectors

I have a table with *n* rows. On these *n* rows I need to set some CSS style, following this rules:

- the CSS should apply only on odd rows
- the CSS should NOT apply on the first and the last row (or on those rows with `.excludeme` class)
- the CSS should apply only on visible rows

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr class="excludeme"><td>first</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr class="showhide"><td>show/hide</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr class="showhide"><td>show/hide</td></tr>
    <tr class="showhide"><td>show/hide</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr class="excludeme"><td>last</td></tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.showhide{
    display: none;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd):not(.excludeme){
    background: orange;
}
```

**JS**

```
//--- #test is a button
$("#test").on("click", function(){
   $(".showhide").toggle(); 
});
```

you can find a fiddle [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7x55m/)

As you can see, when some rows are hidde, the `even/odd` colouring is not respected. I tried this selector

```
table tr:nth-child(odd):not(.excludeme):visible{
    ....
}
```

but is not working.. Is it possible to accomplish this only using CSS?

Thank you

Comment: This is not possible by CSS, you need to use JavaScript to handle this.

Comment: Instead of hidding the element, try removing/creating them (the `.showhide` elements).

Comment: A useful similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8539107/1725764

Comment: @HashemQolami is there some sort of limit on the number of concatenated selector in CSS?

Comment: @BeNdErR: No, the problem is that there is no `:visible` selector in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").on("click", function(){
       $(".showhide").toggle();
        if($(element).is(":visible")){
            // color odd rows
        }
    });
});
```

You have to verify the visibility of elements **before** coloring them. Only color the visible odd elements, not all elements in DOM (visible or not).

I hope that helps, have a good day :)

Comment: I'm looking for a CSS solution, I prefer not to use JS if possible. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

you can use following CSS(use of gradient CSS) without changing any other code:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
table {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    background-image:
    repeating-linear-gradient(white, white 1.2em, hotpink 1.2em, hotpink 2.4em);
    border-collapse: collapse;

}
td,tr {
    border: none;
    padding: 0 5px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    margin: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.showhide {
   display: none;
}

.excludeme {
     background: white;
}
```

Comment: What if the line height grows if the content is very long and multi line?

Comment: you can use colors according to line-height. Suppose it is X then you need to add Css like : repeating-linear-gradient(white, white X, hotpink X, hotpink 2X);

Comment: I have no control or prediction on the line height :\

Comment: you can add line-height as you want. and you can specify width also.